# iOS Default Document files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to ship some default files along with my iPhone/iPad app through app's Document folder.
Because end user should see files using iTunes and can edit it.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

-Rahul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the default files into the App's folder and copy them on App launch into the documents folder, if they are not already in documents folder (in case of reinstall or not first launch).

Answer (score 1):

Do you meant you want to enable file sharing ? If yes then below link may help you.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app

Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Deeps, File sharing is not a problem for me. But I always want to keep some files in App's document folder. These files are actually App supported files.

Comment: Oh Ok then I guess MacMark answer can help you. You need to copy all files in to document folder on first launch only. May be you can use flag in NSUserDefault (isCopied) or anything else for whether it is first time or not.

Answer (score 0):

add the files into the app using absolute path and create sub folders for the content ,which carries the content along with the app and they will be placed in documents folder of the app.

hope this works

TNQ